# Python: generating a "curve fit score"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on a project in which I am trying to model the movement of an object in a [kymograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kymograph). In order to do so, I fit a curve to each line of pixels in an image, and append the location of the vertex to approximately model the location of the object in the image. Below is a sample image.

[image: Image to be analyzed]

As you can see, early in the time series (at the top of the image) the position of the object is nicely focused and easily modeled with a Gaussian curve. However, closer to the end of the time series (at the bottom of the image), the peak is much more diffuse.  I suspect that the data at the bottom of the image will be fit much more closely by a curve modeling a Poisson distribution (image below, right) while the data at the top/middle of the image will be fit much more closely by a Gaussian or polynomial curve (image below, left).

[image: good and bad examples]

Is there any way to, for each line of pixels, fit more than one curve to the same data and then score each for a least-squares fit?  This way, I could (hopefully) switch models midway through an image to accommodate changing behaviors of the object that I am trying to track.  My current code is below:

```
from PIL import Image

def populateData(picture) :
    """Open an image and populate a list of lists with the grayscale value"""
    im = Image.open(picture)           
    size = im.size                    
    width = size[0]                   
    height = size[1]                   
    allPixels = list(im.getdata())      
    pixelList = [allPixels[width*i :    
                       width * (i+1)] for i in range(height)] 
    return(pixelList)

rawData = populateData("testTop.tif")   

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def findVertex(listOfRows) :

    xList = []
    for row in listOfRows :
        x = np.arange(len(row))
        ffunc = lambda x, a, x0, s: a*np.exp(-0.5*(x-x0)**2/s**2) 
        p, _ = curve_fit(ffunc, x, row, p0=[100,5,2])
        x0 = p[1] 
        xList.append(x0)
    xArray = np.array(xList)    
    return(xArray)

xValues = findVertex(rawData)

def buildRows(listOfRows) :
    yArray = np.arange(len(listOfRows))
    return(yArray)

yValues = buildRows(rawData)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

image = ndimage.imread("testTop.tif",flatten=True)
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.imshow(image)
axes.plot(xValues, yValues, 'k-')

axes.set_title('testLine')
axes.grid()
axes.set_xlabel('x')
axes.set_ylabel('time')
plt.show()
```

[image: program output]

EDIT:
This is the file I used as an input (testTop.tif)
[image: input image]

Comment: "Is there any way to, for each line of pixels, fit more than one curve to the same data and then score each for a least-squares fit?": yes, least square fit works like that. I don't get your question but it seems that you have specific algorithmic problems regarding your dataset. Well, this is something you should figure out yourself and it's not really python/numpy or scipy, let alone stackoverflow related.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work out some form of [goodness of fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) between the fit and your data. Taking the sum of the squared differences between your current fit (a Gaussian) and your data divided by the variance.

```
sumerrsq = 0.
for i in range(yValues.shape[0]):
    sumerrsq += np.power(yValues[i] - xValues[i],2)

goodfit = np.sqrt(sumerrsq/var)
```

I think you can use use the second output from curve fit (the covariance) to get the variance,

```
p, pcov = curve_fit(ffunc, x, row, p0=[100,5,2])
var = np.diag(pcov)
```

You can then check the value of goodfit and if it is not sufficient, switch to a different distribution. In using a different distribution, you may need to use a different estimation of error (this assumes the errors are normally distributed).

Note, without the data (and not being sure what array was which) I couldn't test any of this code...

Answer (score 0):

According to the `curve_fit` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use `perr =
>   np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`.

So if that's the value you're trying to compare, then you could take that second returned value from `curve_fit` (the one you are currently assigning to `_`), use it to calculate `perr` as above, and compare the error between multiple curves.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you work with a 2D fit model. A 1d Gaussian distribution is the basis but the mean and variance depend on position and time. You then would fit the model against the 2d image data.

In case you want to stay with your approach, it looks like it's just the starting value for mean and variance which you need to tweak in order to get a better fit for the lines with large times.

To your question, you can model any score function you want, so you could do something like:

```
def score(x,y):
    if x < 10:
         return x**2 - y
    else:
         return x - y
```

So in order to work with two different models in different ranges, follow this example.